# In pyspark dataframe.write.json() adds extra empty line at the end.Is is good idea to write more records using in df.write.json

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

We have a dataframe with 5 columns with nearly 1.5 Billion records.

We are need to write that a single line (single records) as json.

We are facing two issues

1. df.write.format('json') is writing all as single line or single record
   but there is second line (empty line is coming) we need to avoid it
2. df.write.format('json').save('somedir_in_HDFS') is giving error

We want the save the file as single file so that the downstream application will read it

Here is the sample code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *


schema = StructType([
    StructField("author", StringType(), False),
    StructField("title", StringType(), False),
    StructField("pages", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("email", StringType(), False)
])

# likewise we have 1.5 billion records
data = [
    ["author1", "title1", 1, "author1@gmail.com"],
    ["author2", "title2", 2, "author2@gmail.com"],
    ["author3", "title3", 3, "author3@gmail.com"],
    ["author4", "title4", 4, "author4@gmail.com"]
]




if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    dfprocessed=df #here we are doing lots of joins with other tables
    dfprocessed = dfprocessed.agg(
        f.collect_list(f.struct(f.col('author'), f.col('title'), f.col('pages'), f.col('email'))).alias("list-item"))
    dfprocessed = dfprocessed.withColumn("version", f.lit("1.0").cast(IntegerType()))
    dfprocessed.printSchema()
    dfprocessed.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").option("escape", "").save('./TestJson')
    #the above write adds one extra empty line
```

```
We are facing two issues 
1. df.write.format('json') is writing all as single line or single record 
   but there is second line (empty line is coming) we need to avoid it
2. df.write.format('json').save('somedir_in_HDFS') is giving error
```

Comment: what error df.write.format('json').save('somedir_in_HDFS')  is giving?

Comment: "Error occurred in save_daily_report : An error occurred while calling o149.save.
:org.apache.spark.sparkException:Job aborted
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasource.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasource.InsertIntoHadoopFSRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFSRelationCommand.scala:159)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(command.scala:104)

Comment: ...
 ..
 ..
 caused by org.apache.spark.sparkException:Job aborted due to stage Failure:Task 26 in stage 211.0 failed 4 times,most recent
 failure:Lost task 26.3 in stage 211.0 
 ExecutorLostFailure(executor xxx exited caused by one the the running task)Reason:Container maked as failed
 Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
 Killed by external signal

Driver stacktrace:
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failedJobAndIndependent
 Stages (DAGScheduler.scala:1890)

Comment: we are using below configs in spark-submit

spark-submit --conf spark.port.maxRetries=100 --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
 --executor memory 16g --executor-core 4 --driver-memory 16g
 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=10g 
 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
 --cong spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutor=30
 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutor=15
 --code.py